# How to set default value to version column for existing data?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, optimistic-locking

I am trying to use optimistic locking.
I am adding the version column to my table how do I set the default value to the version column for existing data or this is sufficient on entity?

```
@Version
@Column(name = "VERSION")
private Long version = 0L;
```

Comment: Is this your question: *scenario* You have some already existing entities in the database (without version column) and now you want to add the optimistic locking; *question:* how to add a version value to the already existing entities?

Comment: Yes that is right @Ralph

Answer (score 1):

The most easiest way it to do this in the database.

Of course you need to add the version column anyway: something like:

```
 alter table MyEntity add column version INT(11); //no not null constraint here!
```

and then just add the first value to all entities:

```
 update MyEntity set 'version' = 1;
```

*now you can also add the not null constraint*

```
 alter table MyEntity modify version INT(11) NOT NULL;
```

(I expect that you stop the application while you add the version column).

Answer (score 0):

In case of Oracle as a database - use with values option for nullable columns

```
alter table MyEntity add column version INT(11) default 0 with values
```

for not-null columns - DB will updates to default value for existing rows

```
alter table MyEntity add column version INT(11) not null default 0
```

> From Oracle-11g onwards, default values are retrieved from metadata
> for null values on modified field, Oracle does not perform update on each row to fill default values.
> see - https://chandlerdba.com/2014/10/30/adding-not-null-columns-with-default-values/