# Optimistic locking with multiple record insertion in same table

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, optimistic-locking

Trying to use optimistic locking implementation. So I followed below steps

1. Create version filed in the table
2. Same filed defined in entity class

Entity looks like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "txn_customer")
public class TxnCustomer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "TXN_ID")
    private Integer txnId;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "TXN_DATE")
    private Date txnDate;

    @Column(name = "CASHMEMO_NUMBER")
    private Long cashmemoNumber;

    @Column(name = "INVOICE_AMOUNT")
    private double invoiceAmount;
    
}
```

Now I am trying to insert 2 records into txn_customer table using JPA. I have below code

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public TransactionResponseDTO saveTransaction(RequestDTO requestDTO) {
    TxnCustomer object1 = saveTxnCustomer(requestDTO);
    repo.save(object1);

    TxnCustomer object2 = saveTxnCustomer(requestDTO);
    repo.save(object2);
}
```

While executing above code then getting below exception

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "current" is null
    at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.next(IntegerType.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.next(IntegerType.java:22) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Versioning.increment(Versioning.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getNextVersion(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:430) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:307) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:229) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3303) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2438) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    ... 73 common frames omitted

org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:571) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
```

Can someone please let me why I am getting this issue/or how to solve this one?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "current" is null` check this

Comment: what its trying to say about to "current" ?

Comment: is this happening after adding the version? try adding `@Column(name = "version", nullable = false)`

Comment: Yes.. After adding version this issue started coming... I have created this column into existing table

Comment: try setting the default version 0 or 1

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509851/how-to-set-default-value-to-version-column-for-existing-data

Comment: @deadshot Thanks for your help. Its working fine now. The only issue I am getting that version value always inserted as 0. Its should be increase correct?

Comment: yeah, it will increase, or you can keep the default value in db, write an update query add default version to existing entities

Comment: Any idea like why its not increasing?

Comment: check this post it has similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321280/jpa-version-field-doesnt-get-incremented